# Is it required to use the Developer Console to query data from Apex?

Tags: apex, soql

I want to query my object data directly from Apex. I was wondering if its required to use the 'Developer Console' in Salesforce, or if I can use VS Code? If you can do both which would you recommend?

Comment: Note that SOQL is separate from Apex.  You can use various tools to execute SOQL alone and get the resulting data.  With Apex, you can run SOQL queries but perform other actions as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Here's what I found:**

You can query your object data directly from Apex either with the ***Developer Console*** in Salesforce or ***VS Code***. However, using VS Code provides several advantages over the Developer Console.

With VS Code, you can develop your Apex code and LWC components in a local development environment and deploy them to your Salesforce org. This allows you to compare code changes, version control your code, and collaborate with other developers more easily.

The file extension for the apex file is: `.cls`

Comment: You can also use Workbench, Data Loader or, for that matter, any IDE including VsCode, IlluminatedCloud, ...

Comment: **Update:**  Don't create the class using the 'New File...' Use the drop down menu instead via 'SFDX: Create Apex Class'.